# evaluation sum power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am trying to understand power series, could someone review this exercise?
So basically I need to find the sum of the following power series$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(4x)^n$$
So basically I need to use this formula and do some substitutions$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$
So if we substitute $x = -4t$ we get $$\frac{1}{1+4t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-4t)^n$$ which is kinda what I want right? So, can I conclude that $$\frac{1}{1+4x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(4x)^n$$?
Now, supposing that this is the correct result(which probably isn’t) how can I find the sum of this series. Could someone show me a general approach for finding the sum of a series?. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You did find the correct expression. Just substitute the value of x to whatever you want, now.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct. This is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) with common ratio $r=-4$ and coefficient of each term $a=1$. You can find some derivations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/370662/infinite-geometric-series-formula-derivation). You may also find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3818305/is-there-a-geometrical-reason-why-for-x-geq-0-and-a-natural-number-n-frac/3818374#3818374) useful.

Note that we require that $|x|<1$ for the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$ to converge. Thus we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(4x)^n=\frac{1}{1+4x}$$

which converges when $|x|<\frac{1}{4}$.